# How to remove element from Heap::Simple in Perl

Tags: perl, heap, element

Is there a way to remove a specific element from the heap using the [Heap::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~thospel/Heap-Simple-0.13/lib/Heap/Simple.pm) module? There is only a method to remove the top element.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove anything but the top of a heap then you don't want a heap structure. You normally only need a heap if you're working with data graphs or something similar. What problem are you working on? And won't a simple hash do what you want?

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. A good place to use a heap is a list of timers, where you add events that happen in the future, peek the top element to find out when to set the next timer, and pop the top element when the timer expires. But sometimes users ask to cancel a timer before it expires.

Comment: @hobbs How do you cancel that timer?

Comment: @Schwen: are you maintaining an event queue? It would help us if you explained your application. If you need to access all the items in a heap independently of that heap then you would have to make it a heap of pointers to item data. Deleting an item then involves just marking the item as deleted so that it can be ignored when it is pulled from the heap.

Comment: Sorry, it seems you've got me mixed up with the OP.  I was more prodding @hobbs into explaining how one deals with the "sometimes users ask to cancel a timer before it expires" part.  It seems the answer would be of use to the OP.

Comment: @Schwern you delete it from the heap, obviously. :)

Comment: @hobbs: a `heap` stops being a heap if you have access to anything but the topmost element. Removing the root (top) element from a `heap` is much simpler than removing a random element from anywhere inside it, and if you think you need to do that then it implies bad design or a misunderstanding of the data structure. I would be surprised if a similar question arose about a `stack`, no matter how useful such a device may be.

Comment: @Borodin While I agree that if you're going to do that *a lot* you should avoid a heap, access beyond the topmost does not define a heap. I'd thought that was true about heaps, but my research into various kinds of heaps shows it's not that simple. For example, the Fibonacci heap is O(nlogn) to delete an arbitrary element, probably because it's made of trees. You can also design a stack which allows efficient access to the middle.

Comment: @Schwern: it may help to think of a `stack` in the same way. The nature of a stack is that `push` and `pop` are the only operations available, so only the topmost element is accessible. Yes, there are *stack-like* data structures, for instance in hardware that allows an entire stack frame to be popped at once, but these are not stacks. In the same way *Fibonacci* and *Binomial* heaps differ from a standard binary heap if only because they consist of multiple trees so that there is no single *root* which is the next node to be removed.

Comment: I wonder how proponents of the *remove from anywhere* heap suggest that the node to be removed should be specified? Because the internal data structure of the heap is private, it seems to me that the only way is to provide pointers to every node in the heap. Given that, there is no problem with simply marking a node as deleted, and thereafter treated deleted nodes like blank lines in a file.

Comment: @Borodin You specify by key like `$heap->delete($key)`. A binary heap is a binary tree, its nodes have keys (or the value serves as a key). Each node is greater than or equal to its children.  One can walk down the heap/tree searching for the node in question, an O(logn) operation.  Then you treat that node as the root of its own heap and do a normal heap root delete, also O(logn).  Of course the heap has to support this method, but it requires no special restructuring.  Different heap types do it differently, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: @Schwern: You can't use the key to find the node to delete unless you restrict the heap to unique keys, which is a special sort of heap. And it's *possible* to delete from the middle of a stack as well, but if you do that you shouldn't be using a stack.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Heap::Simple does not support extracting anything but the top node.  You have to remove everything up to the one you want to remove, and then put everything else back.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Heap::Simple;

my $heap = Heap::Simple->new;

$heap->insert(1,2,3,4,5);

# Remove 1, 2 and 3
my $item_to_remove = 3;
my @items = $heap->extract_upto($item_to_remove);
pop @items;

# Put 1 and 2 back    
$heap->insert(@items);

# 1, 2, 4, 5
say join ", ", $heap->keys;
```

More sophisticated heap types deal with deleting elements better.  [Fibonacci heaps](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) have an efficient delete operation.  [Binomial heaps](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Binomial_heap) can efficiently merge other heaps, which makes the "insert them back" part faster.  There are some implementations of more sophisticated heaps on CPAN, but you should profile before you get too deep into optimization.

The general algorithm or removing an arbitrary node from a binary heap isn't much different from deleting it from a binary tree, since binary heaps are just a special case of a binary tree.

1. Starting at the root, walk down the tree searching for the node in question.
2. Treat that node as the root of its own heap and delete it normally.

Both are O(logn) operations and pretty efficient.